# Align decimal number multiplied by power of 10 in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

How can I make the decimal number in a table to be aligned, knowing that these numbers multiplied by a power of 10.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Gradient of the log-likelihood using analytical expression and Matlab central finite differences approximation}
\label{tab:Gradient}
\begin{center}   
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Gradient & SCKF\textsubscript{analytical} & SCKF\textsubscript{central} \\
\midrule
Gradient w.r.t $\bm{a_e}$      & $1.63076989\cdot10^4$  & $1.63076989\cdot 10^4$ \\
Gradient w.r.t $\bm{\kappa_e}$ & $-0.37241217\cdot10^4$ & $-0.37241217\cdot 10^4$ \\
Gradient w.r.t $\bm{a_i}$      & $0.24443907\cdot10^4$  & $0.24443907\cdot 10^4$ \\
Gradient w.r.t $\bm{\kappa_i}$ & $-0.13204648\cdot10^4$ & $-0.13204648\cdot 10^4$ \\
Gradient w.r.t $\bm{c}$        & $0.01407282\cdot10^4$  & $0.01407282\cdot 10^4$ \\
Gradient w.r.t $\bm{d}$        & $0.38486354\cdot10^4$  & $0.38486354\cdot 10^4$ \\
Gradient w.r.t $\bm{\epsilon}$ & $-4.01712927\cdot10^4$ & $-4.01712927\cdot 10^4$ \\
Gradient w.r.t $\bm{\kappa_s}$ & $1.15246120\cdot10^4$  & $1.15246120\cdot 10^4$ \\
Gradient w.r.t $\bm{\tau}$     & $-0.00272403\cdot10^4$ & $-0.00272403\cdot 10^4$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Do you want to align at the decimal point itself?

Comment: `dcolum` or `siunitx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with a simplified code, based on `siunitx` and a nicer looking first column:

```
\documentclass{article} %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, makecell, caption}%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \sisetup{table-format = -1.8e2, table-number-alignment=center}
  \caption{Gradient of the log-likelihood using analytical expression and Matlab central finite differences approximation}
  \label{tab:Gradient}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{>{\boldmath$}l<{$}SS}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[c]{Gradient \\[-1ex]w.r.t. }} & {SCKF\textsubscript{analytical}} & {SCKF\textsubscript{central}} \\
    \midrule
    \multirowcell{9}{\begin{matrix*}[l]a_e \\ \kappa_e \\ a_i \\ \kappa_i \\ c \\ d \\ ϵ\\ \kappa_s \\ τ\end{matrix*}} & 1.63076989e4 & 1.63076989e4 \\
                                                & -0.37241217e4 & -0.37241217e4 \\
                                                & 0.24443907e4 & 0.24443907e4 \\
                                                & -0.13204648e4 & -0.13204648e4 \\
                                                & 0.01407282e4 & 0.01407282e4 \\
                                                & 0.38486354e4 & 0.38486354e4 \\
                                                & -4.01712927e4 & -4.01712927e4 \\
                                                & 1.15246120e4 & 1.15246120e4 \\
                                                & -0.00272403e4 & -0.00272403e4 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Package [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) is your friend:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  exponent-product=\cdot,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Gradient of the log-likelihood using analytical expression
    and Matlab central finite differences approximation}
  \label{tab:Gradient}
  \begin{tabular}{
    l
    S[table-format=-1.8e1]
    S[table-format=-1.8e1]
  }
    \toprule
    Gradient & SCKF\textsubscript{analytical} & SCKF\textsubscript{central} \\
    \midrule
    Gradient w.r.t $\bm{a_e}$      &  1.63076989e4 &  1.63076989e4 \\
    Gradient w.r.t $\bm{\kappa_e}$ & -0.37241217e4 & -0.37241217e4 \\
    Gradient w.r.t $\bm{a_i}$      &  0.24443907e4 &  0.24443907e4 \\
    Gradient w.r.t $\bm{\kappa_i}$ & -0.13204648e4 & -0.13204648e4 \\
    Gradient w.r.t $\bm{c}$        &  0.01407282e4 &  0.01407282e4 \\
    Gradient w.r.t $\bm{d}$        &  0.38486354e4 &  0.38486354e4 \\
    Gradient w.r.t $\bm{\epsilon}$ & -4.01712927e4 & -4.01712927e4 \\
    Gradient w.r.t $\bm{\kappa_s}$ &  1.15246120e4 &  1.15246120e4 \\
    Gradient w.r.t $\bm{\tau}$     & -0.00272403e4 & -0.00272403e4 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @ Heliko Oberdiek, thanks this is what I want.

Comment: @ Heliko Oberdiek,  Another question what means by S[table-format=-1.8e1] and why specifically this number 1.8e1, thanks for advance.

Comment: @user137684 `-`: place for sign, `1`: one digit before the decimal marker, `8`: eight digits after the decimal marker, `e`: exponent, `1`: one digit for the exponent; it is explained in the  [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) of package `siunitx`.